# Unit testing Coverage report not showing on SonarQube Dashboard

Tags: c++, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

Our Sonar Build Environment details as follows:

```
* SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.6 (64-Bit). 
* Sonar Client Build Operating System – Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (64-Bit). 
* Sonar-scanner- Version - 3.0.3.778.
* sonar-cxx-plugin-0.9.7.jar
* Source Code Language: C++
* gcovr Version - 3.3
```

**Current Problem:**

We have Unit testing coverage report (Gcovr - .XML based - CoverageReport.xml) file, Sonar doesn’t show any error message in log, also it is not showing coverage information on SonarQube Dashboard.
My sonar-project.properties file has below information to import my coverage report.

```
sonar.cxx.coverage.reportPath=VE_L/CoverageReport.xml
```

Sonar Scanner Log not showing any error. Whereas I can see import successful.

```
10:28:23.717 INFO  - Scanner found '1' report files
10:28:23.717 INFO  - Parser will parse '1' report files
10:28:23.921 INFO  - Added report '/home/srinivas.ghs/Jenkins/workspace/VE_Engine/MORE_SERVICE/VideoMaker/Development/DREAM/VE_L/CoverageReport.xml' (parsed by: CoberturaParser) to the coverage data
10:28:24.080 INFO  - Project 'scm.team.videoeditor' Cycles:0 Feedback cycles:0 Tangles:0 Weight:0.0
10:28:24.081 INFO  - Sensor CxxSquidSensor (done) | time=11057ms
```

Note: I have Configured Unit Tests Coverage & Integration Tests Coverage Wedgits.

So could you help me to display my unit testing coverage report on SonarQube Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before the `gcovr`:

`find . -iname "*.gcno" -o -iname "*.gcda" | xargs gcov`

Comment: Hi Luis, Shall i use same gcovr Version - 3.3 (Or) do i need to use gcovr version - 2.4?

Comment: Noup (i think), because the gcovr parse the files of gcov, that is the reason that you must run gcov before gcovr

Comment: With gcovr-3.3 version generated report modified the filename with complete path. Post that able to view results in sonarqube dashboard. Thank you.